# Swift is unable to type-check expression in reasonable time

Tags: swift, xcode

The following function triggers the error: *"The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"*

```
func calculateCalSpent(age: Int, height: Int, currentWeight: Int, activityLevel: Int ) -> Int{
    var cal = Int(66.47 + (13.75 * currentWeight) + (5.003 * height) - (6.755 * age))
    print(cal)
    return cal
    // Men kg cm
}
```

When I put 1 instead of cal in return, everything is okay. What should I do?

Comment: Break up each parenthesis into a variable of its own, it will narrow down the issue

Comment: I took the liberty and edited the question title and remove the SwiftUI tag, the problem is not related to SwiftUI. Please edit this if you feel my edit was inappropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing integers and floating point values. That seems to pose a problem for the type checker in this particular case.

Since you need floating point calculations here, explicitly cast all `Int` to `Double` to fix/work around this:

```
var cal = Int(66.47 + (13.75 * Double(currentWeight)) + (5.003 * Double(height)) - (6.755 * Double(age)))
```

Comment: "might be worth a bug report for the Swift project" operator overloads are quite hard and expensive to resolve, especially on operators such as `+` and `*`, which have lots of overloads, so this is a well known problem, no need to log further bugs for this. Operator overloads are especially tricky to resolve when there is a type error in the code, hence the operation resulting in a timeout rather than a type system error.